# Azure ARM Template Condition with AND operator

Tags: json, azure, templates

Is it possible to use an AND operator in a condition?  For example, if first Parameter is "Apple" and second Parameter B is "Banana" then deploy a resource?  My example below is only for if Parameter A is "Yes"

```
  "condition": "[equals(parameters('firstParameter'), 'Apple')]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "name": "deployRandomResource",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
```

Comment: not sure why the downvote, legitimate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, just nest those one inside the other:

```
"[and(equals(fooooo), equals(baaaaar))]"
```

you can also nest more expressions:

```
"[not(or(equals(something, something), and(something, something)))]"
  ^   ^ if any of the arguments are true - or returns true
  ^ this read like invert the result: true becomes false and false becomes true
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!